# Is it possible to create 2 Kafka Template with same key value for 2 different producer factories?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I try to create 2 different kafka template with same key value for 2 producers.

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate <String, byte[]> kafkaTemplateProducer1(){
      return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory1)}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate <String, byte[]> kafkaTemplateProducer2(){
      return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory2)}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> producerFactory1{...}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> producerFactory2{...}
```

That has a problem. @Primary must be added. I define it on kafkaTemplateProducer1(). Then I want to call kafkaTemplateProducer2 in another class :

```
@Qualifier("kafkaTemplateProducer2")
final KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template;
```

But nevertheless I get the kafkaTemplateProducer1. How can I get the correct one? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Why do you need `@Primary`? What is an error without that?

Comment: What other properties are unique across these client configs that requires more than one?

Comment: Error without Primary:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.kafka.KafkaPublisher required a single bean, but 2 were found: 
 kafkaTemplateProducer1
 kafkaTemplateProducer2
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as Primary Annotation, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using Qualifier Annotation to identify the bean that should be consumed.

Comment: It is needed to connect to 2 different kafka clusters simultaneously. Therefore I disabled Spring Boot's auto configuration and configured the properties beans for each cluster.